# Is this possible? Replace xxx (MySQL string) with the next item from a text list

Tags: python, bash

I have a list with domains which I want to enter in my MySQL database.

The SQL string I am using is the following one:

```
INSERT INTO `ap_field_logic_conditions` (`form_id`, `target_element_id`, `element_name`, `rule_condition`, `rule_keyword`) VALUES
(11282, 3, 'element_1', 'is', 'xxx'),
(11282, 3, 'element_1', 'is', 'xxx'),
(11282, 3, 'element_1', 'is', 'xxx'),
(11282, 3, 'element_1', 'is', 'xxx'),
(11282, 3, 'element_1', 'is', 'xxx'),
(11282, 3, 'element_1', 'is', 'xxx'),
(11282, 3, 'element_1', 'is', 'xxx');
```

Anyways, you get the idea.

Now I have a list (.txt file) with 1200 domains, like this:

```
domaina.com
domainb.com
domainc.net
domaind.org
domainz.net
```

Is there a way, I can replace xxx with the next domain from the list automatically?

I have no scripting knowledge, but I am guessing this can be done some kind of bash script or pythong?

...or maybe there is an easier solution for this in general?

Sorry for the lack of details or explanation, but I think it's clear what I am trying to achieve (or I hope so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
values = []
val_pattern = "(11282, 3, 'element_1', 'is', {}),"
with open('domains.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        values.append(val_pattern.format(line.strip()))

request = r"INSERT INTO `ap_field_logic_conditions` (`form_id`, `target_element_id`, `element_name`, `rule_condition`, `rule_keyword`) VALUES {}"
request = request.format(' '.join(values))

with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(request)
```

You may save this as 'formatter.py' and run like this:
python formatter.py

NB! I hope you using python 2.7

Comment: Thank you for you help and details. I only had to add '' to {}. And it wasn't working on Python 2.6, so I moved to a different server with Python 2.7.x and it worked (after the change I made). Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You can generate this by using a bash `while read` loop to go through each line of the second file.

```
echo 'INSERT INTO `ap_field_logic_conditions` (`form_id`, `target_element_id`, `element_name`, `rule_condition`, `rule_keyword`) VALUES';
while read domain; do
    echo "(11282, 3, 'element_1', 'is', '$domain'),"
done < file.txt | sed '$ s/,$/;/'
```

The echo at the start is to generate the `INSERT` statement.  The last `sed` command means "on the last line" (`$`) "replace comma+end of line" (`s/,$`) "with a semicolon" (`/;/`).

Answer (score 2):

In Python,

- set the first part of the string — we do that in two steps to keep line length relatively short — note also that ① we use triple quotes, not to worry about quoting inside string and ② we added a newline character at the end

  ```
  head = '''INSERT INTO `ap_field_logic_conditions`(`form_id`, `target_element_id`,'''
  head = head + ''' `element_name`, `rule_condition`, `rule_keyword`) VALUES\n'''
  ```
- set the remainder of the string using the `join` method of the string `',\n`, by which we join a sequence of strings using the given strings

  - the sequence is built iterating over the contents of your text file (this returns the file contents line by line, handy isn't it?) and formatting the domain name into the fixed string that you showed us,

    ```
    tail = ',\n'.join('''(11282, 3, 'element_1', 'is', '%s')'''%dom.rstrip('\n')
                          for dom in open('domains.txt'))
    ```
- eventually we print the two parts to stdout, using the null string as separator between printed items (the default is a blank space `' '`)

  ```
  print(head, tail, ';', sep='')
  ```

Put all of the above in a file, say `add_domains.py` and execute the script,

```
$ cat add_domains.py
head = '''INSERT INTO `ap_field_logic_conditions`(`form_id`, `target_element_id`,'''       
head = head + ''' `element_name`, `rule_condition`, `rule_keyword`) VALUES\n'''
tail = ',\n'.join('''(11282, 3, 'element_1', 'is', '%s')'''%dom.rstrip('\n')
                              for dom in open('domains.txt')) 
print(head, tail, ';', sep='')
$ python3 add_domains.py > my_SQL_string
$ more my_SQL_string
INSERT INTO ...
```